# How to create regex that adds a space after every 3-4 letters?

Tags: regex

how to create a regex that automatically adds a space after every 3-4 letters?

I currently have a regex created, but it will add a space only after adding a letter to the input:

```js
function format(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/\d{3,4}?(?=..)/g, "$& ");
}

console.log(format(1234567890));
console.log(format(123456789));
console.log(format(1234567));
console.log(format(123456));
console.log(format(1234));
console.log(format(123));
```

So the output is like this.

```
123 456 7890
123 456 789
123 4567
123 456
1234
123
```

How to rebuild this regex so that the output is like this?

```
123 456 789 0
123 456 789
123 456 7
123 456
123 4
123
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use `\d{3,4}`? It matches 3 or 4 digits. Don't you simply want `\d{3}` - matching 3 digits?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `..` is requiring two characters after the match. If you want to allow one character after the match, remove one of the wildcards:

```js
function format(s) {
    return s.toString().replace(/\d{3,4}?(?=.)/g, "$& ");
}

console.log(format(1234567890));
console.log(format(123456789));
console.log(format(1234567));
console.log(format(123456));
console.log(format(1234));
console.log(format(123));
```

This produces the exact output you are looking for.

Comment: You're right, and even better if I removed the last dot as well ```/\d{3,4}?(?=)/g, "$& "``` The problem, however, is that it puts a space at the end of the input. Even if I have the maxLength = "16" attribute set on the input, it always allows me to add the last space. Please know how to eliminate this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have only digits, you can also match 3 digits and assert a non word boundary after it using the pattern `\d{3}\B`

```js
function format(s) {
  return s.toString().replace(/\d{3}\B/g, "$& ");
}
console.log(format(1234567890));
console.log(format(123456789));
console.log(format(1234567));
console.log(format(123456));
console.log(format(1234));
console.log(format(123));
```